# windows update uninstall batch file

Tags: batch-file, uninstallation, windows-update

KB3114409 KB2825678 windows update patch files you may know that has caused many user to only be able to launch outlook in safe mode. that means i can not find anybody in outlook, anyway it is no good patch to me.

so i made batch file for our staff that is for uninstalling windows patch about KB3114409 KB2825678. it seems to be looking those file and uninstall. but if i have a look in installed update console, there is still remain those two.

## i execute this batch file in administrator mode as well, but still same in.

@echo off
Wusa /KB:3114409 /Uninstall 
Wusa /KB:2825678 /Uninstall

## exit

i made it like that, but i still have those patches...
i use win7 64bit and using user mode, not administrator mode.
please any idea..?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you really have everything on one line or if your post just turned out that way. This is what I use:

```
@echo off
start "" /b /wait wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:3114409 /quiet /norestart
start "" /b /wait wusa.exe /uninstall /kb:2825678 /quiet /norestart
```

To put all commands on one line you would need to separate them with &
but that makes it a bit harder to read. Also see WUSA /?

Comment: it was turned out just that way! wow i will try like that  ;) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use MSIEXEC to remove this patch since its an "Office patch" and not for Windows.

Tutorial and script approach described at: http://blog.jocha.se/tech/uninstall-outlook-kb3114409